Book series with multiple pantheons based on historical Earth religions and a final war
I was hoping someone can help me remember a book series I read sometime between 1986-1988. A friend lent me the book so I don’t remember if it was published then or if it had been around for many years.
Some of the key points I remember:

the protagonist is trying to learn magic but he isn’t sure which path to take
there are multiple different pantheons based on many different regions around Earth
one character he meets is a powerful disciple of a specific pantheon so he asks if he can apprentice but can’t since only the pure of heart and soul can be accepted (i.e. rejected if they followed any other pantheon before)
there are many Norse overtones and Yggdrasil is central to the protagonist
there is a massive war at the end that kills many but our protagonist survives (barely)
the forest homeland of our protagonist is destroyed by fire during the final battle


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many books were there in the series?  Do you recall the cover art?

Was this a post-apocalyptic world?  Where there were a lot of neo-primitives, but some high tech remained?

Hi,I can’t remember well but I think a trilogy.
It was high fantasy so not anything like Shannara
